# Shortcut to check if field is not empty in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function(event) {
        if ($("#name").val() == '')
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#name").css("border", "solid 2px #ff0000");
        }
        else if ($("#day").val() == '')
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#day").css("border", "solid 2px #ff0000");
        }   
        else if ($("#month").val() == '')
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#month").css("border", "solid 2px #ff0000");
        }
        else if ($("#year").val() == '')
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#year").css("border", "solid 2px #ff0000");
        }
        else if ($("#email").val() == '')
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#email2").css("border", "solid 2px #ff0000");
        }
        else if ($("#pass").val() == '')
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#pass").css("border", "solid 2px #ff0000");
        }   
        else if ($("#pass2").val() == '')
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#pass2").css("border", "solid 2px #ff0000");
        }           
        else
        {
            $("#submit").submit();
        }
    });
});
```

So I am checking one by one, if field is empty, if yes, it will mark the border with red color.
If not, submit().

But that's so messy, is there a way to make it shorter?

Like using an array?

Comment: Yes, why dont you use an array with an for-loop?

Comment: You should probably use `event.preventDefault()` ???

Comment: @adeneo Did you understand my question?

Comment: I got confused, I've never seen that many preventDefault's before ?

Comment: Yeah my fault, meant to erase it.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var valid = true;

        $(':input', this.form).each(function(i, ele) {
            if (ele.value.trim() == "") {
                ele.style.border = '2px solid #ff0000';
                valid = false;
            }
        });

        if (valid) this.form.submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: You could delete the condition and the `preventDefault` just by doing `return valid`

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = ['#name','#pass']; //etc

$.each(arr,function(i){
   if ($(this).val()=='') {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).css(...);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.

The classic way to do it is to add a `class="required"` on your input and then do :

```
var emptyInput = $('.required[value=""]')
if(emptyInput.length != 0){
    event.preventDefault()
    emptyInput.css("border", "solid 2px #ff0000")
}
```

If you dont want to change your DOM, change that :

```
var emptyInput = $('.required[value=""]')
```

for that :

```
var emptyInput = $('input:text[value=""]')
```